# Adding the Title field to the new document set form

Tags: 2013, document-set

I've been searching this for days and can't find an answer.  Lots of folks seem to want to know how to hide or remove the title field.  I need the opposite.  For some reason, for document sets only, I can't figure out how to put the Title field on the new document set entry page.

I've tried making it both optional and required, no dice.  SPD doesn't seem to give you an option to edit NewDocSet.aspx like you can new item forms, at least not that I can tell.

Anyone else have/resolve this issue?

Comment: If you set the Title field to required, it will provide the Title field on the form after you select the file to upload. At least, that is the case in SharePoint 2010. Would that not accomplish what you want?

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not the case in 2013.  At least, not for the document set.

Comment: Why do you need this? Would a new required field with display name titel fulfill your requirements?

Comment: To reduce the crappy user experience of having the users have to go back to the thing they just created and input the title, which is different from the name field.  So, yes, we could just create a fake title field and use workflow to write that to the actual title field, but that seems a little silly, doesn't it?